# StackExchange Link Error

Tags: support

Shenanigans aside on the meta board. :) I get this message pretty frequently when I click on the StackExchange logo at the top. If I click on the error to dismiss, I can then click on any of the links, `hot questions`, `all sites`, `inbox`, with out any issues. I'm using IE9. I've tried using it in compatability mode with the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

on meta only or on other sites? I can't repro this, and we've heard of no other instances.. can you try in a different web browser just to rule out potential browser configuration issues?

Comment: I think I have this figured out. I was able to reproduce the issue with Firefox as well. It seems I'm getting click happy with the stackexchange link and click on it before the page finishes loading. When I noticed I get a notification, that loads up first, I click on it and I'll get the error message, every time. If I wait for 5 seconds for the page to finish loading it won't happen at all.

Comment: ah, excellent, that helps. We'll see what we can do to address that.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour too (and identified it as "clicking too quickly"); the problem is that the server is returning a 418 response.  Hopefully that helps you track it down, Jeff.

Comment: I didn't answer your question about meta or not. It happens on all of them. Normal SF, SU, SO, Startups.